# Retornar a quantidade de caracteres de uma lista de palavras com TypeScript

Tags: typescript, caracteres

Quero retornar um método que recebe uma lista de palavras e retorna um array com a quantidade de caracteres das palavras. Tentei conforme abaixo, mas está retornando a quantidade de palavras ao invés dos caracteres.

```
   //Cria lista de palavras

    var caracteres:string[] = new Array( "Celular", "Carro", "Pessoa" );

    function quantidadeCaracteres( a, b )
        return a + b;
    }
    console.log( caracteres.length );
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```js
//Cria lista de palavras

    var caracteres:string[] = new Array("Celular","Carro","Pessoa");
    var total = caracteres.toString();

    function quantidadeCaracteres( a, b ){
        return a + b;
    }
    console.log( total.length );
```

Comment: Neste caso soma 1 caractere a mais em cada palavra, seria devido ao uso da vírgula?

Comment: Isto pela vírgula.

Answer (score -1):

Bem tu podes usar o metodo map existente no ES6 te aconselho a ler mais sobre a API.

Mas a ideia é precorrer todo array e a cada vez que precorreres detectas o tamanho de cada palavra e no fim ter uma variavel que contem o total de cada palavra.

```
var caracteres: string[] = new Array("Celular", "Carro", "Pessoa"); // Teu Array
let total: number[] = caracteres.map((caractere) => caractere.length); // Metodo que mapeada cada registro e retorna o total
console.log(total); //Exubicao do total
```